# How to output files with a specific extension (like .csv) in Hadoop, using MultipleOutputs class

Tags: java, file, hadoop, mapreduce

I currently have a MapReduce program that uses `MultipleOutputs`to output the result into multiple files. The reducer looks like this:

```
private MultipleOutputs mo = new MultipleOutputs<NullWritable, Text>(context);
...
public void reduce(Edge keys, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String date = records.formatDate(millis);
        out.set(keys.get(0) + "\t" + keys.get(1));
        parser.parse(key); 
        String filePath = String.format("%s/part", parser.getFileID());
        mo.write(noval, out, filePath);
    }
```

This is very similar to the example in the book *Hadoop: The Definitive Guide* - however, the problem is that it outputs the files as plain text. I want my files to be outputted as .csv files and haven't managed to find an explanation on it in the book or online.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to iterate through your output folder after the completion of the Job object in your driver to rename the files?

As long as you emit  in your reducer (the text should be the line in the csv with the values separated by semicolon or whatever you need) you can give a try to something like this:

```
Job job = new Job(getConf());
//...
//your job setup, including the output config 
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
//...
boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
if (success){
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(getConf());
    FileStatus fs[] = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(outputPath));
    if (fs != null){ 
        for (FileStatus aFile : fs) {
            if (!aFile.isDir()) {
                hdfs.rename(aFile.getPath(), new Path(aFile.getPath().toString()+".csv"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's an interesting approach, but my files end up being blank when the '.csv' extension is added. There should be text in the output files which is separated by tabs "\t" which might have something to do with it.

Comment: If you tab them, use .tsv. Excel can open them correctly.